# nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: abc.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out]

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, cas

I am looking to authenticate google using CAS. And I am getting error as

> org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: xyz.com:389; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: abc.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out]

My LDAP credentials are correct. When I use AD LDAP, I can login successful but if I use Luminis LDAP credentials, we are getting error.

- Maven version: Apache Maven 3.3.9
- CAS version: 3.5.2
- Tomcat version: 7.0.70
- Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation

Any suggestions?

Thank you in Advance.

Bob.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got the solution:

The cas server does not have access to LDAP server. so I had to add cas server's ip to firewall of LDAP server on port 389.
And it works just fine.